# Tracing the Tradition of HaRav Shimshon Rafa'el Hirsch

Tags: history, rabbis, ashkenazi, mesorah-tradition, samson-raphael-hirsch

I'm not sure if this is the proper forum for such an investigation; but, I'll pose the question and find out. I'm trying to trace the tradition received by HaRav Shimshon Rafa'el Hirsch through the ages (i.e. who were his teachers and their teachers, etc.).

So far, Googling has led me back as far as [HaRav Ya'aqov Yehoshua' ben Tzevi Hirsch Falk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Joshua_Falk) (author of [Pene'i Yehoshua'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pene_Yehoshua)). But, I'm having difficulty tracing the tradition further back from Pene'i Yehoshua'. Does anyone know who Pene'i Yehoshua' received his tradition from or, more generally, how to go about such research?

For completeness' sake, here is the trail I've uncovered thus far:

- [Rav Shimshon Rafa'el Hirsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch) learned from [Rav Isaac Bernays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Bernays)
- Rav Isaac Bernays, in turn, learned from [Rav Avraham Bing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Bing)
- Rav Avraham Bing, in turn, learned from [Rav Nathan Adler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_Adler)
- Rav Nathan Adler, in turn, learned from [Rav David Tevele Schiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tevele_Schiff)
- Rav David Tevele Schiff, in turn, learned from [Rav Ya'aqov Yehoshua' ben Tzevi Hirsch Falk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Joshua_Falk)

Comment: The WP entry is based on a [Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/view.jsp?artid=60&letter=J&search=Yaakov%20Yehoshua%20ben%20Tzvi%20Hirsch) entry which cites a few pages in four books. I'd recommend trying to find those books in a library as a next step.

Comment: ["Knesset Yisra'el"](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46814&st=&pgnum=567) from Rabbi Shmu'el Yosef Fin (Fuenn)

Comment: While it might be interesting to see the chain of tradition, I don't think it sheds much light on Rav Hirsch's teachings and their sources. He is not commonly viewed as continuing their tradition. He often cites his rebbe Rav Isaac Bernays, so there you have a point, but beyond that, although I have studied his writings extensively, I don't recall him citing those earlier rebbes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Hebrew Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2_%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%A7) he received Semicha from the [Chacham Tzvi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzvi_Ashkenazi).

> קיבל סמיכה מאת [החכם צבי](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99)

Still following the trail at Hebrew WP, he, in turn, learned from his grandfather, [R' Ephraim Hakohen](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5799-ephraim-ben-jacob-ha-kohen) ([אפרים הכהן](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F)), author of the commentary *Machaneh Ephraim* on the Torah.

He, in turn, learned from [R' Moshe Lima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Isaac_Judah_Lima) ([משה לימא](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%90)), author of the commentary *Chelkat Mechokeik* on *Shulchan Aruch - Even Ha'ezer*.

He, in turn, learned from [R' Joshua Höschel ben Joseph of Cracow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_H%C3%B6schel_ben_Joseph), who wrote a book of responsa also called *Pene Yehoshua'*.

He, in turn, learned from [R' Samuel ben Uri Shraga Phoebus of Cracow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_ben_Uri_Shraga_Phoebus) and [R' Joshua ben Alexander HaCohen Falk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Falk).

The earlier R' Joshua [Falk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Falk#Note_on_the_name_.22Joshua_Falk.22), in turn, learned from the *[Rema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles)* and the *[Maharshal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Luria)*.

Comment: I got a little carried away.

Comment: Delicious! Thank you, Gershon Gold and @IsaacMoses!!

Comment: Do you think it's too far-fetched to expand the question's scope to go further back? Rabbi Lawrence Kelemen, in one of his talks, said he went through the exercise of tracing a Rabbi's teaching back to Moshe Rabbeinu...

Comment: @Lee, I'd suggest being happy with what you have here and maybe starting a new question about the Rema or the Maharshal if you want, since many Ashkenazi rabbis from the last few centuries probably trace their *mesora* back to these major figures.