# Tracing the Tradition of HaRaM"A (Moshe Isserles)

Tags: history, rabbis, ashkenazi, mesorah-tradition

In [tracing the tradition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57787/2091) of HaRav Shimshon Rafa'el Hirsch, I arrived at the famed [RaM"A (Rav Moshe Isserles)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles) with help from the beloved MY community. As Rabbi Lawrence Kelemen mentions having done in one of his shi'urim, I'd like to try to trace HaRaM"A's tradition back as far as possible.

Here is the trail I've uncovered thus far:

- Rav Moshe Isserles (and [Rav Shelomo Luria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Luria), HaMaHarSha"L) learned from [Rav Shalom Shakhna of Lublin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalom_Shachna)
- Rav Shalom Shakhna of Lublin learned from [Rav Ya'aqov Pollaq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Pollak) ([Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A7))
- Rav Ya'aqov Pollaq learned from [Rav Ya'aqov Margolioth of Nuremberg](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10405-margolioth#anchor8)<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. Note that the [Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10405-margolioth#anchor8) is not fully convinced of this link. However, the [Jewish Encyclopedia at Daat.co.il](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=2289) and a footnote in ["Kereti U'Peleti"](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_14431_18.pdf) (Rav Yehonatan Eibeshitz) do support the link.</sup>

Comment: Look in the following books:
Artscroll Early Acharonim
Artscroll Rishonim
Herald of Destiny
and books by R. Zecharya Fendel
Hatzlacha!

Comment: @S.H. If you have info to post from those books, that would be great!

Answer (score 4):

SimpleToRemember.com has a [mesorah chain](http://www.simpletoremember.com/articles/a/mesora/) that goes up through the RaM"A. From Rashi to the RaM"A looks like this:

> Rav Shlomo Yitzchaki - ‘“Rashi’” (1105)
>
> R’ Shmuel ben Meir (Rashbam) (1174)
>
> R’ Yaakov ben Meir (Rabbenu Tam) (1171)
>
> Eliezer Me-Metz (1175)
>
> Rokeach (1238)
>
> R’ Yitzchak of Vienna (Ohr Zaruah)
>
> Rav Meir of Rothenberg (1293)
>
> R’ Yitzchak of Duren (Shaarei Durah)
>
> R’ Alexander Zusiein Hakohen (Agudah) (1348)
>
> Meir Bar Baruch Halevi (1390)
>
> R’ Sholom of Neustadt
>
> R’ Yaakov Moelin (Maharil) (1427)
>
> R’ Yisroel Isserlein (Trumas Hadeshen) (1460)
>
> R’ Tavoli
>
> Rabbi Yaakov Margolies (1501)
>
> Rabbi Yaakov Pollak (1530)
>
> Rabbi Sholom Shachna (1558)
>
> Rabbi Moshe Isserles ‘“Rama’” (1572)

Unfortunately it doesn't provide the sources it relied on for making that chart.

Comment: Your final remark kind of this down a bit. On the other hand, did most Ashkenazi rishonim have a mesorah from Rashi?

Comment: i believe this chart comes from r' kelemen